# Google 'CONSENT' cookie - What is it?

Tags: cookies

I am trying to create a detailed Cookie Policy for my website. There is one cookie that is set by Google that I can't find any information on, the cookies is...

> CONSENT

I can hazard a guises at what the cookie is used for but I am looking for some official documentation on it. I have searched through Googles docs but haven't been able to find anything out.

Can anyone shed any light on it?